# "Multiple Commands Produce" for all Cocoa Pods when Archived

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I try to archive an app on Xcode, I receive many errors regarding the cocoa pods saying that "multiple commands produce...". I believe it is because the app has multiple build schemes using the same cocoapods. One app from the project was able to archive, but the other scheme that I created won't work.

Errors:

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework':
1) Target 'GTMSessionFetcher-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
2) Target 'GTMSessionFetcher-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework':
1) Target 'nanopb-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework'
2) Target 'nanopb-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/nanopb.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework':
1) Target 'Alamofire-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework'
2) Target 'Alamofire-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations.framework':
1) Target 'FirebaseInstallations-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations.framework'
2) Target 'FirebaseInstallations-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CryptoSwift.framework':
1) Target 'CryptoSwift-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CryptoSwift.framework'
2) Target 'CryptoSwift-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CryptoSwift.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework':
1) Target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework'
2) Target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DropDown.framework':
1) Target 'DropDown-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DropDown.framework'
2) Target 'DropDown-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DropDown.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCore.framework':
1) Target 'FirebaseCore-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCore.framework'
2) Target 'FirebaseCore-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseCore.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FBLPromises.framework':
1) Target 'PromisesObjC-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FBLPromises.framework'
2) Target 'PromisesObjC-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FBLPromises.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework':
1) Target 'BoringSSL-GRPC-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework'
2) Target 'BoringSSL-GRPC-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/openssl_grpc.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseABTesting.framework':
1) Target 'FirebaseABTesting-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseABTesting.framework'
2) Target 'FirebaseABTesting-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseABTesting.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore.framework':
1) Target 'FirebaseFirestore-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore.framework'
2) Target 'FirebaseFirestore-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/leveldb.framework':
1) Target 'leveldb-library-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/leveldb.framework'
2) Target 'leveldb-library-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/leveldb.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/grpcpp.framework':
1) Target 'gRPC-C++-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/grpcpp.framework'
2) Target 'gRPC-C++-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/grpcpp.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SwiftSoup.framework':
1) Target 'SwiftSoup-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SwiftSoup.framework'
2) Target 'SwiftSoup-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/SwiftSoup.framework'

error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/JGProgressHUD.framework':
1) Target 'JGProgressHUD-iOS14.0' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/JGProgressHUD.framework'
2) Target 'JGProgressHUD-iOS14.2' has create directory command with output '/Users/ryanreid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gradeApp-hiztjiltybrjmzegfnwrcjdgwmii/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Gaels Connect/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/JGProgressHUD.framework'
...
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'gradeApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for gradeApp

  target 'gradeAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'gradeAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

  pod 'JGProgressHUD'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
  pod 'SwiftSoup'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 4.1'

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'

end


target 'Gaels Connect' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Gaels Connect

  pod 'JGProgressHUD'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
  pod 'SwiftSoup'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 4.1'

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'

end
```

I also receive warnings as the build begins to archive for most/all cocoapods:

```
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework Alamofire'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'Alamofire-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'Alamofire-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework AlamofireImage'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'AlamofireImage-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'AlamofireImage-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework CryptoSwift'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'CryptoSwift-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'CryptoSwift-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework DropDown'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'DropDown-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'DropDown-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework FBLPromises'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'PromisesObjC-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'PromisesObjC-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework FirebaseABTesting'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'FirebaseABTesting-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'FirebaseABTesting-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework FirebaseCore'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Gaels Connect' from project 'gradeApp')
    note: Target 'FirebaseCore-iOS14.0' (in project 'Pods')
    note: Target 'FirebaseCore-iOS14.2' (in project 'Pods')
...
```

Comment: What version of CocoaPods and what version of Xcode?

Comment: Xcode 12.5.1 and CocoaPods 1.9.3

Comment: Recent versions of Firebase/Performance require iOS 10 and it may help to update to CocoaPods 1.10.2

Comment: Just updated the Podfile to iOS 13 and updated CocoaPods to 1.10.2. I am still experiencing the same issues though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the two schemes had two different iOS deployment versions (one was iOS 14 and the other was iOS 14.2). Once I switched them both to iOS 13.0, I was able to archive both apps successfully.

Comment: How did you switched both to ios 13.0. Can you describe the steps?

Comment: @Jestin check Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target

Answer (score 0):

run pod deintegrate then remove podfile.lock then  pod install then set build active architecture to yes
also, it maybe help if u put this at the end of pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
    end
  end
end
```